# Spring - inject application.properties to jar(as Maven dependency)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I want to access my application.properties file from a jar I created and included in my pom.

So in parent project  -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-jar-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And inside the jar I have a class that needs values from the parent `application.properties` file.

I already tried using `spring.profiles.active` by setting `spring.profiles.active=test` and printing JVM args but the values was not injected.

Inside the jar -

```
public class PropertiesRepository  {
    //get application.properties
    public PropertiesRepository(String appName, String instance) {
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();

        for (Iterator iterator = arguments.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String param = (String) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Runtime arg=" + param);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Place your properties file on the classpath (e.g. put it next to the JAR and run the application with `java -cp . -jar some-jar-name.jar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your file will be on the *classpath*, use a `@Configuration` class with `@PropertySource`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:your-file-name.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration { }
```

If your file name is the standard `application.properties`, you don't even need to do that, it will be picked up automatically, and you'll be able to access them via

```
@Value("${your-property}")
```

or

```
Environment#getProperty("your-property")
```

Given you're on `Spring Boot`, everything should work flawlessly with your current dependency configuration.